# How to justify 2 interlocked circles can't be separated

Tags: general-topology

So say I want to justify the claim 2 interlocked circles can't be separated without cutting at least one. Intuitively, this seems obviously true, but I'm unsure of the mathematical terminology used to explain this.

Is there some named theorem that states this? What sorts of terms from topology would describe this claim and it's answer?

Comment: Look up "Hopf link".

Comment: And the field of research is called knot theory.